# Thinking Sphinx sorting integers descending doesn't sort by highest to lowest value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm new to using Sphinx and the Thinking Sphinx gem. I have a column that has up to 6 digit integers in it, when I do a sort on that column I'm only getting up to 5 digits by default
and when it is ordering them it is doing it by only the first digit so it looks like this

```
99999
99998
99997
...
89999
...
79999
...
100999 <- Higher 6 digit number showing up here
10999
10998
```

even though I have numbers higher than 99999 this so it should look like this

```
100999
100998
100997
...
...
99999
99998
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is it stored as a integer in mysql? The sort you get looks like a string sort

Comment: Wow I feel dump now, yes it's a string type. Dealing with badly managed data, thanks.

Comment: Added as an answer since some other people may have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you store integers as integers in your DB.

If it's in a string, no one will complain and everything'll work fine until you want to sort them :)